# IE background fixed resize to cover browser window

Tags: html, css, gradient

code below works in firefox, chrome, etc., but not in Internet Explorer. How to make background to cover browser window, even if there is not much text.

```
body {
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #c0bfbf 100%) center center fixed; /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #c0bfbf 100%) center center fixed; /* Mozilla Firefox */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #c0bfbf 100%) center center fixed; /* Opera */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #e5e5e5), color-stop(1, #c0bfbf)) center center fixed; /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #c0bfbf 100%) center center fixed; /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #c0bfbf 100%) center center fixed; /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#c0bfbf',GradientType=0, sizingMethod='scale'); /* IE6-8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#c0bfbf',GradientType=0, sizingMethod='scale')"; /* IE6-8 */

color:#393939;
font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: set `body` padding and margin to zero.

Comment: I already did, I just removed this part, code updated.

Comment: i think some trouble with `sizingMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the hex codes with rgb values in the linear-gradient tag without the ms-prefix it works in IE10 on windows 8 at least

Here's what I used:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(255,255,0) 0%, rgb(0,255,255) 100%) center center fixed; /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
```

Edit, here's the example with your actual color values in it:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(229,229,229) 0%, rgb(192,191,191) 100%) center center fixed;
```

Comment: thx for reply, but it doesn't on IE9 on win7, and I want to make it work on IE8, IE7 if possible. Your code didn't change anything. `filet` and `-ms-filter` are for those browsers, but my code doesn't cover all browser window. If content finish in the middle of browser window, half page in white.